# A_n in L^2(R) convergence study

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I want to study in $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ the convergence of

$A_nf(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-n(x-y)^2}f(y)dy$

Solving....

It's easy to see that $A_n\to A=0$ pointwise, now i want to show strong convergence with

$||(A_n-A)f||^2\to 0$ using monotone convergence theorem

$||(A_n-A)f||^2=||A_nf||^2=\int_\mathbb{R}|e^{-n(x-y)^2}f(y)|^2dy$

for the Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality $\le\int_\mathbb{R}|e^{-n(x-y)^2}|^2dy\int_\mathbb{R}|f(y)|^2dy$

now $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow f(x)^2\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ so that I have
$\le C\int_\mathbb{R}|e^{-n(x-y)^2}|^2dy$....

How can i conclude this? and for monotone convergence?

Answer (score 1):

$A_nf=f*K_n$, where $$K_n(t)=e^{-nt^2}.$$So Young's Inequality shows that $$||A_nf||_2\le||f||_2||K_n||_1=n^{-1/2}||f||_2||K_1||_1\to0.$$

**Edit** So now the OP asks about uniform convergence. That's even simpler; the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows that $$||A_nf||_\infty\le||f||_2||K_n||_2=n^{-1/4}||f||_2||K_1||_2\to0.$$

Comment: You are right! and what about uniform convergence?

maybe i can say i can't have because there is $n^{-1/2}$?